# Best practice for C program with large number of input files

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a C program that takes 7 input files. I could pass these to my program as command line arguments but it is not exactly succinct and could lead to errors with the order they are provided.

I had thought of creating 1 input file containing the 7 required file names and just passing this to my program.

What is best practice for providing a large number of input files to a C program?

Comment: Unless you're dealing with a low-level simple situation where you are linking in your own C runtime, the order likely shouldn't matter.

Comment: What kind of files? What are the files for? Will you call the program with different files all the time?

Comment: There's no really "best practice" of passing many arguments to a program. There are not many options. One - you can pass it all using command line arguments. Two - you can create a config file with some syntax and pass that config file. The end. `Is this good practice?` - passing 1000 options to postfix is nicer with configuration files. Passing 7 arguments to `openssl` is  nothing special.

Comment: Seems like this depends a lot on the specifics, e.g., are the input files always related (i.e., the same 7 files always together, effectively being one input that just happens to be split into different files) – if so, perhaps you could consider using a naming pattern for them and infer the other names from the first.

Comment: On the other hand if it just happens to be that it needs 7 different files but they are not always tied together, perhaps you can specify the type of each file as an additional command-line argument instead of relying on the order of arguments (e.g., `program -a file.A -b file.B …`).

Comment: Each file has approx. 45 million records with an associated value. Essentially I am reading the values from the input files into a hash map and then I will calculate a weighted average and write this to an output file. The 7 input files are created weekly and are timestamped so the name changes every time they are recreated.

Comment: @daragh You should specify that in the question. Also show exactly how the files are named.

Comment: One way to make it clearer is to use named arguments: `convert --in_data mydata.txt --index myindex.txt --output newdata.txt` is somewhat clearer than  `convert mydata.txt myindex.txt newdata.txt'

Comment: re. name changing due to timestamp, it doesn't prevent using a naming pattern, i.e., a predictable difference. For example, if you have "foo_20190626.aaa", the other files can be "foo_20190626.bbb", "foo_20190626.ccc", etc. Then giving one of the names as an argument allows you to construct the other names. (Again, this is assuming the set of files always goes together. If you mix from multiple sets, then see the named arguments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variety of mechanisms in common use for designating input files to programs, prominent among them (in no particular order):

- separate command-line arguments, possibly with built-in default values (more on this below)
- a common filename stem passed as an argument, with different extensions for the different individual files; the specific filenames are computed by the program from the one stem
- a standard or user-specified file containing the names of the files to operate upon

Combinations of those are possible, and there are other alternatives.  There is no single best practice, and which method or method(s) to choose is to some extent a matter of opinion and personal preference, likely with a dose of the specific practicalities of the particular program.

> I could pass these to my program as command line argument but it is not exactly succinct and could lead to errors with the order they are provided.

I agree.

> I had thought of creating 1 input file containing the 7 required file names and just passing this to my program. Is this good practice?

That is one of the common methods.  Note, however, that although it makes the command line more succinct, it doesn't by itself do much for the ordering issue.

Personally, I wouldn't be too keen on a program that has seven *required* arguments, yet I also wouldn't like being forced to write an auxiliary file just to convey filenames to the program.  To the extent that you do use command-line arguments, I urge you to define them as *options*, in the `getopt()` sense of the term, because mixing up argument order will otherwise be a significant practical problem for your users.  Similarly, if you provide a control file as a way to convey the working file names, then I suggest going to just a bit more effort to use an order-insensitive key / value format.  To the extent that you can provide sensible defaults, that would improve ease-of-use, too.